# IOS Xcode 3.2 - IB not showing design area

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib, xcode3.2

I'm totally new to IOS development and I am trying to create a custom `listView` cell on `Xcode 3.2`.
When I create a new file as described [here](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) I can open the `.xib` file and IB comes up, but there is no place to put the objects, no drawing area, how can I get it to show up?

Comment: why are you using such an old xcode?

Comment: Xcode 5.0.2 is the latest version of Xcode. You should upgrade as it has changed a lot since 3. You will be learning old skills that will not help you at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an ancient version of XCode that no one should be developing on.  A question/answer on the topic of such an old version of XCode is unlikely to be useful to anyone in the future.

Comment: Sorry but this question is not off-topic since i'm using 3.2 because my macbook cannot be upgraded to mavericks so i can't use 5.0

Comment: Xcode 4 requirements are Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard. Can you at least switch to 4??? You're doing yourself a disservice by learning with 3.

Comment: Yes i know but Xcode 4 is not available for download if you aren't registered as developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common thing that happens to me a lot - All you have to do is go to the left-most side right next to the IB, as shown here:

[image]

Right below your File's owner, where you see either the litle white box (as shown at the bottom of the picture) or a yellow circle with that little white box inside of it, just click it, and you should see the view inside of your .xib file - Happy programming!

Comment: Thank you so much Domenico, this is the right solution, i know use xcode 3.2 may sound like silly but actually i can't effort to buy a new macbook and this answer really helps me